# At least how many students are there in the classroom?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, contest-math

> The percentage of students who receive a grade '$5$' is in the range $(3.5 \% , 4 \%)$. At least how many students are there in the classroom?

My idea:

$$3.5 \%<x<4\%$$
$$y_{min} \times \frac {x}{100} \geq 1$$
$$x \geq \frac{100}{y_{min}}$$

So we have,

> $$\begin{cases} 3.5 \%<x<4\% & \\
> x \geq \frac{100}{y_{min}} \end{cases} \Longrightarrow y_{min}=26$$
>
> There are at least $26$ students in the classroom.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Should the range of student is $$\left(\frac{100}{4},\frac{100}{3.5}\right)$$. So atleast 25 students have to be there.

Comment: The range is exclusive. So yes $26$ is the correct answer.